# How to hide NERDTree when vim called with -R option?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-nerdtree

I have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd VimEnter * if !argc() | NERDTree | se nu  | se rnu | endif
```

Also, I have an alias in my `.bashrc`:

```
alias fv='find "$PWD" -maxdepth 1 | vim -R -'
```

After I run `fv` in command line - It opens `vim` with `NERDTree` opened in it. Is there a way to not open `NERDTree` when I run `vim` with `-R` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of just asking if there are no arguments, you could also ask if the buffer is empty.
If you substitute `!argc()` in your `autocmd` by

```
!argc() && bufnr('$') == 1 && line('$') == 1 && getline(1) == ''
```

you should get the desired result.